# Changing animation property in css using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

How do I change the animation property after setting it inside of a css file?

This is my css:

```
#ManSprite{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:280px;
    left:140px;
    background-image: url("images/ManSprite.png");
    z-index:99;
    animation: play .4s steps(2) infinite;
    -webkit-animation: play .4s steps(2) infinite;
    -moz-animation: play .4s steps(2) infinite;
    -ms-animation: play .4s steps(2) infinite;
    -o-animation: play .4s steps(2) infinite;
}

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position: -200px; }
     to { background-position: -600px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
   from { background-position: -200px; }
     to { background-position: -600px; }
}
```

and I've used both of these methods to try and change the amount of steps needed.

```
var ss = document.styleSheets[0];

for(var i =0;i<ss.cssRules.length;i++){
    if(ss.cssRules[i].selectorText === "#ManSprite"){
        ss.cssRules[i].styles.animation = "play .4s steps("+stepsArray[StoryPart]+") infinite";
        ss.cssRules[i].styles.MozAnimation = "play .4s steps("+stepsArray[StoryPart]+") infinite";
        break;
    }
}
```

and I've used

```
var steps = stepsArray[StoryPart];
$('ManSprite').css({"animation": "play .4s steps("+steps+") infinite",
                        "-webkit-animation": "play .4s steps("+steps+") infinite" ,
                        "-moz-animation": "play .4s steps("+steps+") infinite",
                        "-ms-animation": "play .4s steps("+steps+") infinite",
                        "-o-animation": "play .4s steps("+steps+") infinite"});
```

but neither of them work at changing the amount of steps I need in the animation.

Comment: Are you trying to change background-position of the image?

Comment: @AlexShilman Yes I am, but I already have that part. I edited so you can see the css. All I truly need help in is being able to adjust the steps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't know what steps(2) is for - you probably should change just this element in .css() method ...but whatever you want to change in animation specified in css then you need to reset your animation - try doing it like this:

css (change only '#ManSprite' to '.animation'):

```
.animation{
  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position:absolute;
  top:280px;
  left:140px;
  background-image: url("images/ManSprite.png");
  z-index:99;
  animation: play .4s steps(2) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: play .4s steps(2) infinite;
  -moz-animation: play .4s steps(2) infinite;
  -ms-animation: play .4s steps(2) infinite;
  -o-animation: play .4s steps(2) infinite;
}

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position: -200px; }
     to { background-position: -600px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
   from { background-position: -200px; }
     to { background-position: -600px; }
}
```

to start animation:

```
$('#ManSprite').addClass('animation');
```

to change animation:

```
$('#ManSprite').removeClass('animation').css(
    'animation-timing-function','steps('+steps+')' );
$('#ManSprite').addClass('animation');
```

it will work now.

Comment: It definitely is going in the right direction, however after I add it the first time it does not want to update again. Maybe it's something on my side. I'll check again

Comment: did you read my edit? ..which css property is being set to "steps(2)"? what is the name of it? ...you should only change this one in javascript

Comment: animation is a shorthand property - the one i was asking for is `animation-timing-function` i edited my answer - try it now.

Comment: ...and probably you will need to set "-webkit-animation-timing-function", "-moz-animation-timing...." also.

...and i think you need to write separate properties in css instead of a shorthand "animation" - this is how i change my animation and it works just fine.

Comment: Hehe it was my fault. I was setting the animations before I reset the class. Thanks again!! BUUUT can you help me on one small problem? In firefox the method cssStyleSheet.insertRule does not want to work for me. Mind looking at my other question?